# Display message based on count

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have xml file which formatted through XSLFO. I have the following requirement please help me I am new to xslfo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16 ?>
<LINES><LINES_ROW><ATTRIBUTE1> ABCD </ATTRIBUTE1></LINES_ROW></LINES><LINES><LINES_ROW> <ATTRIBUTE1></ATTRIBUTE1></LINES_ROW></LINES>
<LINES><LINES_ROW>  <ATTRIBUTE1>CDEF</ATTRIBUTE1></LINES_ROW></LINES><LINES><LINES_ROW><ATTRIBUTE1>MNOP</ATTRIBUTE1></LINES_ROW></LINES>
```

What I want is: if attribute1 is not empty and not 'ABCD' then count those, and if count is greater than 1 display some message.

Comment: You can't do "if attribute1 is not empty and not 'ABCD'" types of tests with XSL-FO. That is not what XSL-FO is used for. But you can do it with XSLT. Perhaps you are confusing these two technologies?

Comment: Thanks for your update. In XLFO file we have a line <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"> is it means that XSLT version 1.0 is called? If yes please let me know how to do I get the count..

Comment: It means that you have an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet that apparently is used to produce XSL-FO output. Why don't you show us the stylesheet and explain where you got stuck? Also, "*if attribute1 is not empty and not 'ABCD' then count those, and if count is greater than 1 display some message*" is not a very clear requirement.

Comment: The requirement is from erp application where xml source convert to PDF output. the file is too big. if you see my examble it will be clear. I want to count number of attribute1 is not having value ABCD and ''.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="matches" select=".//ATRIBUTE1[string-length(normalize-space(.)) &gt; 0 and not(contains(., 'ABCD'))]"/>
    <xsl:if test="count($matches) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:text>Message of your choice</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Untested though.